# Set content access based on list of users ids

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I have:

- a custom content type: FooBar (folderish)
- a list of users subscribed to a FooBar item (so a list of users ids for each FooBar item) - FooBar members
  I need to have the possibility to allow access to FooBar contents (child items) only for FooBar members (subscribed users in FooBar item's context).

The list of subscribed users is changed multiple times (when a user is approved, rejected, deleted etc).
So, the permissions will be automatically updated in order to give access to particular files only to FooBar members.
Also a member of FooBar item A will not see the contents of FooBar item B only if he subscribes to B, too.

What is the best solution in this case? Will I create a plone group of users for each FooBar item or is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Thanks for asking at https://community.plone.org/t/set-content-access-based-on-list-of-users-ids/7471 !